# iOS GL ES 2 app crashes on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I have an app with a number of render targets/frame buffers and inside one call to glDrawElements it crashes on device ( iPad iOS 5.0) but not in simulator. This is a very shader intensive app with a dozen different shaders and thousands of vertex buffers.

Further debugging the matter turned me to believe that the crash occurs because of a particular shader, but the shader is valid and so is the frame buffer object that is being written to.

Comment: Using if,return,else if,return, return" in a function from a shader is causing a crash, use "if, return, if return, return" instead.

Comment: For one, the Simulator is running on a Mac, which is a far different device in terms of memory and performance characteristics. I've found that it's almost useless to do any sort of OpenGL ES development or testing using the Simulator, so I work almost entirely on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after tons of time spent on debugging I found out that my Depth of field shader was causing the crash, particularly this function :

```
float GetNearFalloff( float Depth, float MinDist, float MaxDist)
{
    float Range = MaxDist - MinDist;
    if (Depth < MinDist)
        return 1.0;
    /*else*/if (Depth > MaxDist)
        return 0.0;

    float Blur = 1.0 - ( (Depth - MinDist) / Range );
    return Blur;
}
```

Basically the commented else there is causing my crash. Removing that made everything work. I put it back actually ( I was thinking it may be something else ), only to see that after a couple of shader recompilations the same crash appeared with the same fix, deleting the *else*.

Comment: I have what seems to be a similar problem, crash inside a apparently else with a return inside. For me removing the return from inside the else statement resolved the crash, but slightly worse solution since the code keeps running a few cycles more. Had you had anymore insights on this ?

Comment: It could've been just an iPad 1 issue where the memory was limited. I have an iPad 2 now and this issue disapparead completely :). I *think* that iOS(and Android too) may not allow the GPU to use the entire RAM, just a percentage of it. I haven't found anything official on this, but more and more experiences are tending towards it. Intel GPUs with shared memory on laptops are doing the same thing so maybe it happens on mobile too.